# Conditional update of SQL Server table column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, substring, conditional-statements, contains

I have to update a table (say table name is `Venues` in SQL Server conditionally i.e. if a column (say column name is `Venue_Name`) in `Venues` CONTAINS sub-string 'C_' then SET a column (say column name is `Venue_Type`) in `Venues` = `Conference`.

I have tried this query as:

```
IF Venue_Name CONTAINS 'C_'
    UPDATE Venues SET Venue_Type = 'Conference'
ELSE IF Venue_Name CONTAINS 'J_'
    UPDATE Venues SET Venue_Type = 'Journal'
ELSE
    UPDATE Venues SET Venue_Type = 'Other'
```

But found error at using the keyword `CONTAINS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE Venues
    SET Venue_Type = CASE 
                        WHEN Venue_Name LIKE '%C[_]%' THEN 'Conference'
                        WHEN Venue_Name LIKE '%J[_]%' THEN 'Journal'
                        ELSE 'Other'
                     END
```

Comment: I think you forgot to use a ESCAPE Character, the underscore will work as wildcard for any character in LIKE.  It should look like this for example: `Venue_Name LIKE '%C#_%' ESCAPE '#' `